# How to work with all subsets in vectorized way

Tags: r, vectorization

I have a stock price dataframe containing a lot of symbols and I would like to perform operations on subsets for every symbol in a vectorized way. My data is :

```
 head(dataset)
        date  open    high   low   close volume  symbol 
1 2014-08-29 34.59 34.6800 34.59 34.6800    200    AAIT 
2 2014-08-28 34.96 34.9600 34.96 34.9600    211    AAIT 
3 2014-08-27 35.28 35.2800 35.28 35.2800    507    AAIT 
4 2014-08-26 35.02 35.0200 35.02 35.0200     00    AAIT 
5 2014-08-25 34.57 35.0200 34.57 35.0200    385    AAIT 
6 2014-08-22 34.80 34.8299 34.80 34.8299    802    AAIT
```

For every symbol I would like to do something like that :

```
for (symb in unique(dataset$symbol){ 
    dataset$night = with(subset(dataset, dataset$symbol == symb), open[-length(open)]-close[-1])
}
```

This causes the last row to be filled with `NA` so I can't do that on the whole dataframe. I could replace the last line afterwards but I would prefer to work with the subsets for more convenience. Is it possible to do the `for` loop in a vectorized way (for loops are very slow on r, it can become a problem if I have too many symbols)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
dataset <- dataset %>%
           group_by(symbol) %>%
           mutate(night = c(head(open, -1) - tail(close, -1), NA))
```

or `plyr`:

```
library(plyr)
dataset <- ddply(dataset, .(symbol), mutate,
                 night = c(head(open, -1) - tail(close, -1), NA))
```

or `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(dataset)
setkey(dt, symbol)
dt[, night := c(head(open, -1) - tail(close, -1), NA), by = symbol]
```

Comment: and a base way: `within(dataset, night <- unlist(by(dataset, dataset$symbol, function(x) c(head(x$open, -1) - tail(x$close, -1), NA))))`

Comment: @rawr, that assumes the symbols are sorted alphabetically. Seems dangerous to me.

Comment: what is the operator `:=` can't find doc on it

Comment: It is part of the data.table package. You can access its do by typing `?":="` but maybe the best would be for you to read the intro vignette that comes with the package.